# Converting dataframe column from object to timedelta and summing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timedelta

I have a Pandas dataframe that I'm segregating by month:

```
months = [g for n, g in df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE',freq='M'))]
```

I'm then taking each month and summing the integers in a columns called `PARTS RUN`.

```
parts_run_month_sum = months[month]['PARTS RUN'].sum()
```

This is all working fine. The last thing I need to do is add the hours together from column `HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)`. This column is an object data type. The data itself it a timedelta format, not datetime. The format is like so: `02:11:40`, being hours:minutes:seconds.

If I run the below line of code, it prints the correct index numbers related to the number of lines there happen to be for each month:

```
for run_time in range(len(months[month]['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'])):
    print(run_time)
```

But if I try to get the lines of times themselves I receive a `KeyError: 0`, although there is a key of 0 in each month that is returned in the above example.

```
for run_time in range(len(months[month]['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'])):
    print(months[month]['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'][run_time])
```

What I'm actually looking for is how to sum the column of times, but because they are objects I cannot do this.

How can I convert a column with format `hours:minutes:seconds` to timedelta and sum the times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'])

#if values are times
df['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'].astype(str))
```

I think instead your solution is possible aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE',freq='M'))['HOURS RUN (HR:MIN)'].sum()
```

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed you even anticipated that they needed to be converted to strings. This did do what I needed and is a better solution changing the whole column df rather than in the loop. Thank you